# Какая максимальная величина стека вызовов JS?

Tags: javascript, стек

Сколько раз функция может вызвать саму себя в js?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34570551/call-stack-size-in-recursive-functions-maximum-call-stack-size-is-lower-than-ex

Comment: считается в байтах, а не кол-вах вызовов функции